# Model is not accepting feature vector for prediction, despite successful compile/train - Keras Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to TensorFlow and neural networks in general. I'm attempting to build a sequential model for a regression problem, with a normalization input layer accepting (112,) and outputting (24,), with some Dense non-linear layers in between. The model below successfully compiles and trains (to a very poor error mean, but that's beside the point). When I attempt to test one of the training samples using model.predict() - from the very same dataset I just trained it on - it breaks and gives me the following error:

```
Node: 'sequential/NonLin_1/Relu'
Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,32], In[1]: [112,512]
     [[{{node sequential/NonLin_1/Relu}}]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_6782]
```

I've done an exhaustive search of the model and can't figure out where this IN[0]: [1,32] size is coming from. Here is the model summary:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 normalization (Normalizatio  (None, 112)              3         
 n)                                                              
                                                                 
 NonLin_1 (Dense)            (None, 512)               57856     
                                                                 
 NonLin_2 (Dense)            (None, 512)               262656    
                                                                 
 NonLin_3 (Dense)            (None, 512)               262656    
                                                                 
 Lin_Output (Dense)          (None, 24)                12312     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 595,483
Trainable params: 595,480
Non-trainable params: 3
_________________________________________________________________
```

Here is the full code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import csv

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

### Read and Format Data
feat = 112 #number of features
outputs = 24 #number of outputs

with open('ForestPathExport.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)
    data = np.loadtxt(csv_file, delimiter=",")
    N = np.size(data, 0)  #determine number of samples
    xtrain = np.zeros((N,feat))
    ytrain = np.zeros((N,outputs))
    for i in range(N):
        xtrain[i,:] = data[i, 0:feat]
        ytrain[i,:] = data[i, feat:(feat+outputs)]

#print(np.shape(xtrain))
#(868, 112)
#print(np.shape(ytrain))
#(868, 24)
print('Data Import Complete')

### Build model
def model1(xtrain):

    normalizer = layers.Normalization(input_shape=[feat,], axis=None)
    normalizer.adapt(xtrain)

    # Build sequential model
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([normalizer,
                              layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', name='NonLin_1'),
                              layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', name='NonLin_2'),
                             layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', name='NonLin_3'),
                              layers.Dense(24, name='Lin_Output')])
    model.summary()

    model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam", metrics=["mean_squared_error"])
    return model

model = model1(xtrain)
history = model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=100, batch_size=190, validation_split=0.2)
xtest = xtrain[1,:]
#print(np.shape(xtest))
#(112,)
test_predict = model.predict(xtest)  #<-----Error
```

Comment: You always need a batch axis in your data, try `xtest = xtrain[1:2, :]` to keep the axis when indexing.

Comment: That was too easy! Thank you for that